Write a PDA that accepts the language of strings over {a, b, c} where the number of instances of ab is equal to the number of instances of bc
As the question is stated above, these are the list of transition functions I currently have:
$alphabet: {a, b, c}$
$start: q0$
$accepting: {q3}$
// Initialization
$q0 ($ _, _ $\rightarrow$ \$, $q1)$
// Track 'a' and 'b' for 'ab' sequence
$q1 (a, $ _$ \rightarrow A, q1)$
$q1 (b, A \rightarrow X, q1)$
// Track 'b' and 'c' for 'bc' sequence
$q1 (b,$ _ $ \rightarrow B, q1)$
$q1 (c, B \rightarrow$ _$, q1)$
// Manage other transitions
$q1 (a, X \rightarrow AX, q1)$
$q1 (b, X \rightarrow X, q1)$
// Handle 'b' followed by 'c'
$q1 (b, X \rightarrow B, q2)$
$q2 (c, B \rightarrow $ _$, q1)$
// States to handle errors or reject
$q2 ($ _, _ $\rightarrow$ _, $ q2)$
// Final acceptance condition checking for balanced stack and empty input
$q1$ (_, \$ $\rightarrow$ _, $q3)$
One of the strings I am testing is 'aaab', which should be rejected, but is currently being accepted. I'm not sure how to change this without messing anything else up. I would love any help. Thank you!

https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/18524/755
